# Validación de datos para un login con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un HTML con un login con 2 inputs de tipo email y password, y JS con un array de objetos de tipo usuario, como hago para que al momento de ingresar un email y una contraseña en el login verifique si los datos ingresados existen en el array, y pueda iniciar sesion

```
function iniciarSesion() {
  var user_ = document.getElementById('user').value;
  var pass_ = document.getElementById('pass').value;

  /*if(user_ === 'hola@gmail.com' && pass_ === '1234'){
        window.location = 'index.html';
    }else{
        alert('Correo o contraseña incorrecta');
    }*/

  if (usuarios.forEach(element => {
      element.email === user_ && element.contraseña === pass_;
    }) === true
  ) {
    window.location = 'index.html';
  } else {
    alert('Correo o contraseña incorrecta');
  }
}
```

Comment: y la estrucura del array? [edit] tu pregunta y agrega la estructura del array

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar el método [**`find()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) para buscar elementos del array y también utilizar la expresión **`!!`** para indicar que si el método **`find()`** encuentra resultados retorne **`true`**, de lo contrario retorne **`false`**, y ya con esta respuesta que nos da el **`find()`** validamos a que condición ir:

```js
const users = [
  { email: 'luis', contrasena: '123' },
  { email: 'chris', contrasena: '456' },
  { email: 'mario', contrasena: '789' },
];

function iniciarSesion() {
  var user_ = document.getElementById('user').value;
  var pass_ = document.getElementById('pass').value;

  // console.log(user_);
  // console.log(pass_);

  var verify = !!users.find(element => element.email === user_ && element.contrasena === pass_)

  console.log(verify);

  if (verify) {
    // window.location = 'verificacion.html';
    alert('¡Correo y contraseña correctos!');
  } else {
    alert('Correo o contraseña incorrecta');
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="user" placeholder="usuario" />
<input type="password" id="pass" placeholder="contraseña" />
<button onclick="iniciarSesion()">verificar</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

introducir el código aquí

```js
const users = [
    { user: 'hola@gmail.com', password: '1234' },
    { user: 'abuelita@gmail.com', password: 'ven abuelita' },
];

const validation = (user, pass) => users.find( ( person ) => (person.user === user) && (person.password === pass));

const login = () => {
    const user = document.getElementById( 'txtEmail' ).value;
    const pass = document.getElementById( 'txtPassword' ).value;
    if ( validation(user, pass) !== undefined ) {
        // window.location = 'page.html';
        alert( `El usuario ${user} es correcto |nais|` )
    }
    else {
        alert( 'Usuario o contraseña incorrectos...' );
    }
}
```

```html
<form>
        <fieldset>
            <input type="email" id="txtEmail" placeholder="E-mail" required>
            <hr>
            <input type="password" id="txtPassword" placeholder="password" required>
            <hr>
            <input type="button" value="Start" onclick="login()">
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Comment: explica brevemente l que tu codigo hace.. puede que para ti sea algo obvio pero para otros lectores no lo es.